# Como retornar estes valores fora do Array?

Tags: javascript

Como que eu faço para pegar todos os valores que estão dentro deste foreach e mostrar fora dele? Ele só pega o último quando dou o ALERT:

```
var arrayAdicional = item.ingrediente_adicional.forEach(function(ingrediente)
{

 prodadicional = ingrediente.ingrediente.nome;

 return prodadicional;

 })

alert(arrayAdicional);
```

Comment: O que você está tetando fazer? Por que o arrayAdicional recebe o retorno do forEach?

Comment: Na verdade desconsidere este arrayAdicional. Bem eu quero passar todos os dados deste foreach fora dele, ou seja em um link para abrir em outra página. Se eu escrever o código do link dentro dele ele vai repetir todos os valores, e vai criar vários links. Eu só quero colocar em um link todos os valores retornados.

Comment: Ex: '<a id=\'btn-modal-ingredientes\' class=\'add-cart btn-modal-ingredientes\' href=\'#dialog\' data-adicionais = ' + arrayAdicional + ' >Abrir</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece-me que queres mapear os valores, e para isso existe o [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) que cria uma nova array com o retorno de cada iteração do loop que o `.map()` cria.

Podes usar assim:

```
var arrayAdicional = item.ingrediente_adicional.map(function(ingrediente){
     return ingrediente.ingrediente.nome;    
});

alert(JSON.stringify(arrayAdicional, null, 4))
```

undefined

Comment: Ok deu certo. Muito obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Com `map` é a melhor escolha, se for seguir pelo `forEach` mesmo poderia ser algo como:

```
var arrayAdicional = [];
item.ingrediente_adicional.forEach(function(ingrediente){

    arrayAdicional.push(ingrediente.ingrediente.nome);
})

console.log(arrayAdicional);
```